# MetisMenue does not collapse well on mobile view SB Admin 2

Tags: menu, metis

I use the "SB Admin 2" Theme for a project.

The integratet Metis Menu works very well on desktop, also on tablet.
But when I visit the page with my phone, the menu doesn't hide completely.
Only when I scroll the page.

You can visit https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html to test ist.

If you shrink the browser as far as its like a mobile screen, the menu does not hide.

I tried to do it on the bottom of my index.html file with `$('#side-menu').metisMenu('collapse');` but it does not work. This is also defined in the sb-admin-2.js file. But it doenst work either.

Can you help me to get the menu hide completly, even on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading the JQuery version to 2.1.3: 
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

There are issues with metismenu with newer Jquery versions: 
https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu/issues/128

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with hiding it with css only

```
.navbar-top-links {
  display: none 
}
```

Or if you don't want to hide it always only on button click. Create a new button with these attributes before your current unordered list (ul)

```
<button type="button" class="collapse-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true">
```

And replace this code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
```

With this code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right navbar-expand-sm navbar-collapse panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse2">
```

I managed to get it working like this only you have to style the button and place it in the correct position.

Comment: The question poses confusion. Can you help me to get the menu hide completly, even on mobile devices?

Comment: The menu on Desktop shows on the left side. When the device is smaller the menu collapses. But in mobile devices it doenst collapse completely.

Comment: You can do this by creating a new button before the `<ul>` with these attributes.
`<button type="button" class="collapse-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true">
    </button>`
Replace this 
`<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">`
with this code
`<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right navbar-expand-sm navbar-collapse panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse2">`

I managed to get it working like this.